# Proxy of ExtJS model

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, extjs4.2

Im using ExtJS 4.2. I have following code:

```
Ext.define('Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'type',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'type_id',
        type: 'int'
    }],

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            update: 'localhost/update'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data' 
        },
        writer: {
            root: 'data',
            encode: true
        }
    }
});

var record = new Model({
    id: 100,
    type_id: 2
});
record.phantom = false;

record.save({
     success: function(record) {
          console.log(record.get('type')); 
     }
});
```

Param of request localhost/update:

data: {id: 100, type_id: 2}

Response:

data: {id: 100, type_id: 2, type: 'type of record'}

Why it

```
console.log(record.get('type'));
```

displays null?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to add `"success": true` to your response or set [`successProperty`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-successProperty) to `null` on your reader.

Comment: Why? Request is successful. record.get('type_id') returns 2.

Comment: Why you removed your answer with my clarification?

Comment: Because with your clarification I realized that you were not trying to load a record, but to save it.

Comment: I suggest to try adding `success: true` to your response because, as shown in the docs link, the proxy's json reader is configured to expect it by default. I've not read through the relevant code to be sure that it is enforced, but that's a possible cause. Regarding, the fact that you can read the `type_id` from your record, in the code you're showing you put it in there yourself when you create the model.